# Manipulating a polygon after few operations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, transformation, polygon

I've two polygons. The polygon have undergone some transformation like rotation and shifting. Suppose after the transformation, say as an example, how do I draw a perpendicular bisector from one of the vertices to the opposite edge and mark it?

```
    \documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[draw,thick,shift={(-2.1213,0 )},rotate = 135.000316] (0,0)--
    (-1,2)--(-2,1)--(-2,-1)--(-1,-2)--(0,0)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=green!40,,draw,thick,shift={(-2.1213,0 )}] (0,0)--
    (-1,2)--(-2,1)--(-2,-1)--(-1,-2)--(0,0)--cycle;
    \draw[latex-latex,thick] (-4,0)--(1,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[latex-latex,thick] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above]{$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I want something like the image below. How do I generally extract information after a transformation about the edges and vertices in general? (say a midpoint of an edge, angle bisectors etc). Thanks in advance. [image].

Comment: View [`tkz-euclide`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf). Possibly exist tools in that package to achive what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using TikZ library `calc` and projection modifiers, this can be achieved in two steps.

Step one, name the coordinates you need by adding `coordinate (name)` after the coordinates (e.g. `\draw (0,0) coordinate (a) -- (1,1);`. These coordinates are transformed together with the path.

Step two, draw the lines using projection modifiers. It is drawn from the point (e.g. `(a)`) to the line (e.g. `(b)--(c)`) it should be perpendicular to (e.g. `\draw (a) -- ($(b)!(a)!(c)$);`.

See TikZ manual for version 3.0.1a, section 13.5.5 The Syntax of Projection Modifiers.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick,shift={(-2.1213,0 )},rotate = 135.000316] (0,0) coordinate (a) --
    (-1,2) coordinate (b) --(-2,1) coordinate (c) --(-2,-1)--(-1,-2)--(0,0)--cycle;
\draw[fill=green!40,thick,shift={(-2.1213,0 )}] (0,0) coordinate (d) --
    (-1,2) coordinate (e) --(-2,1) coordinate (f) --(-2,-1)--(-1,-2)--(0,0)--cycle;

\draw[blue, thick, dotted] (a) -- ($(b)!(a)!(c)$);
\draw[red, thick, dotted] (d) -- ($(e)!(d)!(f)$);

\draw[latex-latex,thick] (-4,0)--(1,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[latex-latex,thick] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]